# NSFileWrapper and plain, old file handles

Tags: cocoa, nsurl, nsdocument, appstore-sandbox, nsfilewrapper

We're porting an app with loads of cross-platform code to Cocoa. Using the low-level file handling routines that directly work on files on disk for loading/saving is a mandatory.

As the `NSFileWrapper` is designed to present the contents of files in memory via `NSData` and abstracts away the actual file-on-disk details we can't use that directly, right?

So to be able to use our low-level file handling code using

- `fopen()`
- `fread()`

and similar ANSI-C stuff we are thinking about

1. using the `NSFileWrapper` APIs of `NSDocument`,
2. write the `NSData` from the file wrapper back to a temp. folder
   (e.g. *~/Library/Caches/*)
3. hand over that temp. file (*~100k .. 1MB*) to the lower levels.

Writing of files would work similarly - just the other way around.

Now - is this approach the simplest way to get **direct access to the files** that the `NSFileWrapper` represents? Are we overlooking some API in file wrapper?

Is there any trouble we could run into - thinking of sandboxing and iCloud in particular..?

As we'd like to support file bundles with more than 1 file we'd rather like to stick with the file wrapper based APIs in `NSDocument` and not use the `NSURL` based methods.

Any feedback/critics appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a direct answer to your question but I do have some mandatory reading for you: the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileCoordinators/FileCoordinators.html) gives an in-depth explanation of the various mechanisms available. I'd pay particular attention to the parts about [File Coordinators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileCoordinators/FileCoordinators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH11-SW1) (used by `NSDocument`, and better for you than trying to hack `NSDocument` just to get some of its functionality) and Techniques for [Reading and Writing Files Without File Coordinators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH5-SW1), which includes safe, asynchronous file access using Grand Central Dispatch.

I hope this helps.